How to efficiently query and aggregate time-series data in GridDB for a specific time window with a rolling sum?
I’m working with GridDB to store and query time-series data. The data represents sensor readings taken every minute and is stored in a container with the following structure:
CREATE TABLE sensor_readings (
    timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    sensor_id INT,
    reading DOUBLE
);

I need to write a SQL query that calculates a rolling sum of the reading values over a 30-minute window for each sensor. The challenge is that the dataset contains millions of rows, and I want to optimize the query to ensure it runs efficiently on GridDB.
Specifically, I want the following:

Ensure that the query can be run efficiently even as the dataset grows, ideally using any GridDB-specific features like partitioning, window functions, or aggregation optimizations.
Calculate the rolling sum of reading for each sensor_id over the last 30 minutes.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
SELECT sensor_id, timestamp, 
       SUM(reading) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor_id 
                          ORDER BY timestamp 
                          RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '30 MINUTE' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_sum
FROM sensor_readings;

However, this query is not performing well, especially on larger datasets. I suspect it’s because GridDB is not handling the rolling sum efficiently across the large time series.
Can anyone suggest how to optimize this query, possibly by using GridDB-specific indexing, partitioning strategies, or SQL techniques for better performance? Also, are there any GridDB-specific features that could help me with time-based rolling aggregations?

What indexes exist on the table? Are you using "interval partitioning" on the table? Have you used "explain analyse" & "getplantxt" - perhaps add that output to the question

Currently, I don't have any indexes set up on the sensor_readings table. The table has millions of rows, and performance is becoming a concern, particularly for the rolling sum query. Based on your comment, I’m considering adding an index on the timestamp column, as it's frequently used in the ORDER BY clause for the rolling sum calculation.
I haven’t yet run EXPLAIN ANALYZE or checked the query execution plan using getplantxt, but I plan to do so to identify any inefficiencies in how the query is executed.

Research the "interval partitioning" as well. I expect you also filter the data by date ranges, not just sorting.
